# SQL Server: Is deleting local .LDF file of a remote database safe?

Tags: sql-server

I used SSMS to connect to a remote database from my PC, done my work, now finished with working with that DB and I will never use it locally anymore however, It has left me with a 26 GB log file on my local machine. Is it safe to manually delete the LDF?

Comment: Deleting the log file of a database is not safe. And connecting to a *remote* database doesn't create anything on the *local* machine. Are you sure you didn't connect to the wrong server? Or did you *copy* the database locally?

Comment: I was afraid someone would say that. I do have a LDF file on my harddrive with a modified date of today. If, remote db does not create anything, I could just go ahead and delete it then right?

Comment: I think you should clarify what you are asking. *Why* was that file created locally if you connected to a *remote* machine? If you copied the data locally, you can easily delete the local database. You can also shrink the log.

Comment: I downloaded a backup set and created a new DB to restore it there.

Comment: If you want to be 100% sure, shut down your system, go to any other computer, connect to the remote server and see that it is in the state you expect it to be. All well? Delete that file.

Comment: @Amit a remote database doesn't create local files. Shutting down will only cause delay, not prove anything

Comment: @KemalEmin then you don't have a *remote* database, it's only a local database. If you don't want the data, you can delete it, and that will delete the log file as well. If you do want it but want to shrink the file, Right click on the database, go to Tasks > Shrink > Shrink Files and select the log

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you're right, but what my method does is use brute force to prove a point (that the local file is not needed)

Comment: @Amit which doesn't need to be proven. Besides, the OP has a *local* database afeter all

Comment: @KemalEmin depending on the recovery mode of the database, you may need to take a log backup before you can shrink the log. Or you can switch the recovery mode to Simple from Database Properties.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - OP has a local **version/copy** that is not needed, and proving the point is much needed or else we would not be having this discussion

Comment: I am sorry to have caused headache for a silly issue.. will delete this question.

Comment: Don't worry about the question, it's fairly legitimate, though I'm not sure how you'll get an actual answer posted. More importantly, what did you end up doing?

Comment: I stopped sql server services, renamed all MDF and LDF files. Re-opened SSMS and started services. Checked everything is in place and working fine. Happily pressed and hold SHIFT while slowly and gently hitting DELETE to the full pleasure :)